# Error when attempting to save Outlook VBA project

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When attempting to save an Outlook VBA project I receive the error:

The save failed. This could be because there was not enough hard disk space, or the project file is read-only.

Hard disk space is certainly not a problem and the project is not marked "Lock project for viewing" on the project properties tab. Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this error and what I can do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at this site I was able to find the location where the Outlook VBA project data is stored:

[Outlook 2007 File Locations](http://www.slipstick.com/config/backup2007.asp)

I saw that there was already a project file (VbaProject.otm) in the directory despite the fact that none of the project contents were showing in Outlook.  (Perhaps the file was corrupt.)  I deleted the bad file and re-imported my macro code from a backup.  I was then able to save the VBA project without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check where you are saving the project to?  Perhaps that location is set for read-only, or you might not have access to it?

-JFV

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the location was not actually read only.